# How to move back a L.divIcon to existing layers in Leaflet Js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I added a L.divIcon to a layer using Leaflet Js and trying to bringBack that layer but marker still showing front to all existing layer. I also tried Bringfront existing layer but marker still on all the layers  , Any alter to move added marker back to all the existing layers in Leaflet Js

Code as Following :

```
  var LayerFeatureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup(); 
  var LabelCount = new L.FeatureGroup();
  map.addLayer(LayerFeatureGroup);
  map.addLayer(LabelCount);
  var LabelMarker = new L.Marker([centerPoint.geometry.coordinates[0], centerPoint.geometry.coordinates[1]], {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'roof-center-label',
        roofId: currentLayer._leaflet_id, 
        html: PanelNumber,
        iconAnchor: [0, 0],
        iconSize: null,
        popupAnchor: [0, 0]
      }),
    })
    LabelMarker.addTo(LabelCount);
    LabelCount.bringToBack();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Leaflet, Marker Icons (including DivIcon's) are placed by default in the [`markerPane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-markerpane) [pane](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-pane), which is above Tile Layers and vector shapes (polygons, polylines, etc.).

If you want to place them at a different position in the "vertical stack", you can use custom panes, with [`map.createPane('myPane')`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-createpane), and passing it to the [`pane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-pane) option of your Marker:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var myPane = map.createPane('myPaneName');

myPane.style.zIndex = 300; // In between tilePane (200) and overlayPane (400)

L.marker([48.86, 2.35], {
  pane: myPane,
  icon: L.divIcon({
    className: 'myDivIcon',
    iconSize: [40, 40]
  })
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('Marker White');

L.marker([48.86, 2.37], {
  //pane: myPane, // Normal behaviour => markerPane.
  icon: L.divIcon({
    className: 'myDivIcon2',
    iconSize: [20, 20]
  })
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('Marker Red');

var circle = L.circle([48.86, 2.35], {
  radius: 3000
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('Circle');

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.control.layers(null, {
  Circle: circle
}, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.myDivIcon {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myDivIcon2 {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```